# Create a GeoPoint array with Javascript API in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're developing a fitness app, but are having problems trying to put the route taken by the athlete on the map (we're using the map layout).

Our custom object has a "course" property that is a GeoPoint array.
Using the JS API, the points are coded as an array of objects.

In the Object browser we can confirm that facebook is creating the object with:

```
"course": [
{
    "latitude": 41.076568603516,
    "longitude": -8.4725370407104,
    "altitude": 0
    },
    {
    "latitude": 41.076583862305,
    "longitude": -8.4725580215454,
    "altitude": 0
    },
    ....
}]
```

But nothing shows on the map. 
All the other properties are being correctly saved.

We also tried creating this points as html meta tags, but no luck either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your App ID and an example story (that isn't showing the map properly)?